# Trying to exclude traffic on specific interface from Mullvad vpn

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, nftables, split-tunneling

I have an ubuntu machine with one interface connected to the internet (through mullvad). A RPi box is connected to another ethernet interface on my ubuntu box. Connection works if mullvad is turned off so now I am trying to exclude all traffic from RPi to the internet from mullvad.

I tried to follow [this guide](https://mullvad.net/en/help/split-tunneling-with-linux-advanced/) but no luck so far.
The interface that RPi is connected to has ip 10.0.0.1. RPi receives an ip from ubuntu in 10.0.0.0/8 range.
Here's what I have:

```
table inet excludeTraffic {
 chain allowIncoming {
    type filter hook input priority -100; policy accept;
    ip daddr 10.0.0.1 ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65;
  }

  chain allowOutgoing {
    type route hook output priority -100; policy accept;
    ip saddr 10.0.0.1 ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65;
  }
}
```

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's having the same problem, here's the solution I came up with after a full day of reading:

```
#!/bin/bash

#define some variables
Primary_Interface="wlp4s0"  # Replace with your primary internet-facing interface
Secondary_Interface="enp0s31f6"  # Replace with your internal interface
Subnet="192.168.9.0/24"

# Configure SNAT to maintain connection
nft add rule ip nat POSTROUTING oifname "$Primary_Interface" counter  masquerade

nft add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname "$Primary_Interface" oifname "$Secondary_Interface" ct state related,established accept
nft add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname "$Secondary_Interface" oifname "$Primary_Interface" accept

#  add a rule to the mullvad's table to allow forwarding of my subnet's packets
nft insert rule inet mullvad forward ip saddr "$Subnet" accept

# set a special mark on packets from and to my subnet for mullvad
nft add rule ip nat PREROUTING ip saddr "$Subnet" ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
nft add rule ip nat PREROUTING ip daddr "$Subnet" ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65

# Enable IP forwarding in kernel
#echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

naturally, this needs to be executed with `sudo`.

The problem with the solution based on mullvad's own tutorial that everybody is sharing is that packets forwarded from a subnet never hit the `input` or `output` hook, going through `prerouting`, `forward` and `postrouting` instead. Here's [a nice diagram](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks) that helped me a lot.

I have Ubuntu on my machine so the syntax here is for `nftables` instead of `iptables`.

You might want to uncomment the last line if you set this up for the first time. In my case I had ip forwarding already enabled.

Unfortunately anything added to mullvad table would disappear whenever I turn mullvad off and then back on. In this case I need to add the rule again manually (or put it in a separate script). I couldn't find a way to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that using IPTables. Here is an example script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables
RPi_IP="10.0.0.2"  # Replace with your RPi's IP
Primary_Interface="eth0"  # Replace with your primary internet-facing interface
VPN_Interface="tun0"  # Replace with your Mullvad VPN interface
Default_Gateway="YOUR_DEFAULT_GATEWAY"  # Replace with your default gateway

# Create an IP set for excluded IPs
ipset create exclude_ips hash:ip
ipset add exclude_ips "$RPi_IP"

# Mark outgoing packets from the IP set
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m set --match-set exclude_ips src -j MARK --set-mark 0x6d6f6c65

# Set up routing
ip rule add fwmark 0x6d6f6c65 table 100
ip route add default via "$Default_Gateway" table 100

# Configure SNAT to maintain connection
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o "$Primary_Interface" -j MASQUERADE

# Enable IP forwarding
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Flush existing rules (optional, use with caution)
# iptables -F
# ipset flush exclude_ips

echo "Excluded traffic from RPi to the internet from the Mullvad VPN."
```

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't work...